# how to implement a longtouch with a ListView?

Tags: android, listview

How do I implement a long touch event into my ListView?  The only useful MotionEvents I see are ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP (there's no ACTION_STILL_DOWN event).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

implement the OnItemLongClickListener interface in your ListActivity or you can use

```
getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){})
```

in the inner class way

Comment: Awesome! Just what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

ListActivity has a ListView, which you can get with:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
```

Then you can create a listener like so:

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() { 
    @Override 
    public boolean onItemLongClick( AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id ) { 
              onLongListItemClick(v,pos,id); 
              return false; 
    } 
} );
```

You then create your handler method:

```
protected void onLongListItemClick(v,pos,id) { 
      Log.i( TAG, "onLongListItemClick id=" + id ); 
}
```

Take a look at this discussion from the [Android Developers](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/14ba131c3ebc49eb) google group

Answer (score 1):

Try setting OnLongClickListner on listview. [See this.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnLongClickListener%28android.view.View.OnLongClickListener%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement base-adapter or array-adapter for fix your issue

In getView() method of adapter you will get view onject and on view object you can set all event like click, Touch, LongTouch and more.